# Using Jasypt to decrypt data encrypted with 3des

Tags: jasypt

I am trying to decrypt some data using Jasypt. The data was not encrypted using Jasypt but using *3Des(TripleDes)*. To provide more info on the encrypted data, the algorithm used is DESede, encoding is *UTF-8*, transformation is `DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding` and this is *Base64* encoded.

Is it possible to decrypt this data using Jasypt?

I have checked a lot of Jasypt related topics and cannot find any clues. I get exceptions varying from `org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException` when I set algorithm to `PBEWithMD5AndDES`, to `org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionInitializationException: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Inappropriate key specification` when I set the algorith to `DESede`.

Please point to the right direction...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should install jce.
This [Link](http://help.boomi.com/atomsphere/GUID-D7FA3445-6483-45C5-85AD-60CA5BB15719.html) may be help you.